# How to find all paths between two vertices using QuickGraph

Tags: c#, path, quickgraph

How to find all paths between two vertices using QuickGraph?
This is my custom graph:

```
public class MyGraph : BidirectionalGraph<State, Event>()
{

}
```

In samples only shortest path. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to solve the same thing - you might want to take a look at this thread on the QuickGraph discussion boards:

http://web.archive.org/web/20171227001009/http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/discussions/39479

Its a bit long but I think the jist of it is that you need to use [Ranked shortest path](http://web.archive.org/web/20171227001642/http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Shortest%20Path&referringTitle=Documentation)